# PostgreSQL count with conditions based on a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called `admin_descriptions` that has the following columns:

`description_id`, `value`, `admin_id`, `valid_at`

And the table `admins` which has the following columns:

`state`

I want a query that given a `description_id` it gives me the count of active admins that are using that description. A description for an admin is considered **used** as long as there is a row in the `admin_descriptions` table that has the `description_id`, a `NOT NULL value` and the `valid_at` is most recent than any other entry that has a `NULL value` for that `description_id`.

So, example data:

```
Row 1:
description_id: 1
value: 'foo'
admin_id: 2
valid_at: '2010-01-10'

Row 2:
description_id: 1
value: NULL
admin_id: 2
valid_at: '2012-01-10'

Row 2:
description_id: 1
value: 'some value'
admin_id: 4
valid_at: '2014-01-10'
```

The count when querying for `description_id = 1` would be 1. It would just consider row 3. Because even tho there is the first row where value is NOT NULL, there is row 2 which valid_at is more recent for the same admin_id and its `value` is NULL.

I have been able to get the count without considering the `valid_at` via:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(ad.id)) AS COUNT
FROM admin_descriptions ad
JOIN admins ON admins.id = ad.admin_id
WHERE ad.description_id = 1
AND admins.state = 'active'
```

How can I modify this query to take into account the `valid_at` for each admin_id/description_id combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `distinct on` to get the most recent admin description and then do the aggregation from there:

```
select count(*) as num_valid_admins
from (select distinct on (ad.admin_id) ad.*
     from admin_descriptions ad
     where ad.description_id = XXX
     order by ad.admin_id, ad.valid_at desc
    ) ad
where ad.value is not null;
```

Comment: Gordon Linoff, I asked a continuation question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807715/multiple-ids-on-subquery-to-calculate-counts in case you feel like helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should allow you to check valid_at for each of the grouped id.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(ad.id)
FROM admin_description ad
  INNER JOIN admins ON admins.id = ad.admin_id
    AND admins.state = 'active'
WHERE
  1 = 1
  -- AND valid_at -- However you want to handle valid_at
GROUP BY ad.id;
```

Assuming that each admin_id/description_id combination are always unique.

If not, maybe you can try grouping `id, admin_id, description_id` first to filter out duplicates first.

Comment: `admin_id/description_id` are not unique. That's the main problem. Just the latest (ordered by valid_at) should count in order to decide if it should be added into the final count or not.