# Multiple ids on subquery to calculate counts

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query:

```
select count(*) as num_valid_admins
from (select distinct on (ad.admin_id) ad.*
     from admin_descriptions ad
     where ad.description_id = XXX
     order by ad.admin_id, ad.valid_at desc
    ) ad
where ad.value is not null;
```

which successfully given a `description_id` it gives me the count of admins that are using that description. A description for an admin is considered used as long as there is a row in the `admin_descriptions` table that has the `description_id`, a NOT NULL value and the `valid_at` is most recent than any other entry that has a `NULL` value for that `description_id`.

So, for this type of data:

```
Row 1:
description_id: 1
value: 'foo'
admin_id: 2
valid_at: '2010-01-10'

Row 2:
description_id: 1
value: NULL
admin_id: 2
valid_at: '2012-01-10'

Row 2:
description_id: 1
value: 'some value'
admin_id: 4
valid_at: '2014-01-10'
```

The count when querying for `description_id = 1` would be 1. It would just consider row 3. Because even tho there is the first row where value is NOT NULL, there is row 2 which `valid_at` is more recent for the same `admin_id` and its value is NULL.

Now, I am trying to modify the query so that I can query it for multiple `description_ids` and I can't figure out how to modify the query. What I would like is a set of results that look like: `description_id, count`.

I have tried modifying the inner query like this:

```
select count(*) as num_valid_admins
from (select distinct on (ad.admin_id) ad.*
     from admin_descriptions ad
     where ad.description_id IN (x,y,z)
     order by ad.admin_id, ad.valid_at desc
    ) ad
where ad.value is not null
GROUP BY ad.description_id
```

But is not returning me the counts by `description_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the description id to the `order by` and `distinct on`:

```
select ad.description_id, count(*) as num_valid_admins
from (select distinct on (ad.description_id, ad.admin_id) ad.*
     from admin_descriptions ad
     where ad.description_id IN (x, y, z)
     order by ad.description_id, ad.admin_id, ad.valid_at desc
    ) ad
where ad.value is not null
group by ad.description_id;
```